# Java netty can only take X number of request per second?

Tags: java, networking, nio, netty

Java netty can only take X number of request per second? With the selector approach is it true that it can be a bottleneck in terms of serving request per second? We find that when the traffic is high, clients are unable to connect through, resulting in a time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not due to selector being a bottleneck, but either due to TCP having too few [ephemeral ports](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html) on the clients or due to server hitting [the file descriptor limit](http://support.zeus.com/zws/faqs/2005/09/19/filedescriptors).

Comment: It's not the client, each client only makes one connection. It's not the file descriptor because I am able to connect to that server on another port without time out.

Comment: Why is this the correct answer when he clearly states it wasn't the problem? Someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

There's an increasing view that you shouldn't use Selectors, just hundreds of thousands of threads. Selectors move the scheduling process into the application where arguably it doesn't belong. Also they were designed when the alternative was a *process* per client. A *thread* per client is orders of magnitude cheaper.

Comment: I know this is old, but aren't TPC models falling off? I've read almost everywhere that using TPC for large-scale networking applications is a bad idea, which is why most people suggest moving away from OIO